# Is there any way to include OG tags from loaded content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, facebook-opengraph

Good day everyone. I've got web-app on React + React Router and now one of the features people want from me is proper OG tags for social networks. Head is made of 'Helmet' component, which is rendered after the loading of page content is finished, but Facebook or VK doesn't wait for it to load (or doesn't even execute load code?) so i get only index.html's default OG. Any idea how i can make this work without server-side editing?

Comment: no other way im afraid. i was also ended up having to rewrite to support server side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was trying completely wrong approach. I've added wordpress plugin called "WPSSO Core Free – Essential" and implemented constant URL's for my pages so it worked flowlessly.